# Testing function with document.location

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, redux

I need help with testing action which using document.location.
I'm running react/redux + sinon/mocha.
Here is my action:

```
export function importFile(file) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(importFile());

        return jQuery.post('/api/import/', {file}).done((data) => {
            window.location = `/edit/${data.id}`;
        }).fail((err) => {
            return dispatch(importFileError(err));
        });
    };
}
```

If u run my test in command line - i can not check if there was a redirect to page after `done`, but if i run my test in browser i had redirect and all other tests was dropped. 
Here is my test:

```
it('should create an action to upload import file', (done) => {
            const id = '123';
            const file = 'testname';
            const server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
            const expectedActions = [
                {type: actions.IMPORT_FILE}
            ];
            const store = mockStore({}, expectedActions, done);
            store.dispatch(actions.importFileUpload(file));
            server.respondWith([201, { 'Content-Type':'application/json' }, `{"id":"${id}","version":12}`]);
            window.XMLHttpRequest = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
            server.respond();
        });
```

What is the best way to test functions like this? Prevent redirect or use a wrapper for redirect function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fairly complex piece of code I test with Mocha, in order to isolate it from Mocha I run it in an `iframe`. This prevents my application from messing up the Mocha tests. It should work also to prevent assignments to `window.location` from stopping the tests as `window.location` is local to the frame. (The `Window` object in the frame is a different object from the one in the page that contains the frame.)